# Custom Javascript Button URL Parameters

Tags: apex, javascript, custom-object

I am attempting to use a visualforce page instead of a standard new button. I have an object **Line__c**  that has a master detail relationship to another object **Line_Type__c**.

I have a Line__c related list on Line_Type__c detail page. This is where the button is going. What I want to accomplish is that, when my button is clicked, pass in the URL, the value of the master (Line_Type__c) ultimately setting the lookup field in my VF page with the value of the current Line_Type__c record we are on.

```
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
 {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 

    var url = 'apex/LinePage?CF00NJ0000001LOR6={!Line_Type__c.Name}&CF00NJ0000001LOR6_lkid={!Line_Type__c.Id}';


    if(window.parent != null){ 
    window.parent.location.href = url; 
    }
    else{ 
    window.location.href = url; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> since its a Visualforce you dont need to worry about using IDS of form element .A simple merge field  would do ,provided you properly pass the parentId as paremeter when button is clicked

Lets assume your url from List button will be like

```
apex/LinePage?Parent_Id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Now its easier to obtain this is using page  parameter to auto populate,provided you have standard controller

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Parent_Id}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using some queries in my controller instead of passing it via URL